# PHP foreach loop used in Wordpress wp_customize->add_control

Tags: php, wordpress, foreach

I'm trying to make a list of Google Font choices to use in a dropdown in the WordPress Customizer but I am having difficulty getting this loop right:

```
$i = 0;
foreach ($items as $font_value => $item) {
    $i++;
    $str = $item['family'];
}
```

The string above need to be inside in the array below to generate a list of choices:

```
$wp_customize->add_control( new WP_Customize_Control( $wp_customize, 'ounox-fonts-display-control', array(
    'label' => 'Fonts Section',
    'section' => 'ounox-fonts-section',
    'settings' => 'ounox-fonts-display',
    'type' => 'select',
    'choices' => $str
)));
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `choices` argument [**expects** an array](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Customize_Manager/add_control) , and not a string, so you would need to save each `$item['family']` into an array instead, and then add that array to the argument.

Hapstyx is also correct in pointing out that you don't need the `$i++` to iterate your loop.

The array that `choices` expects for your drop down options should look something like this:

```
$choices = array(
    'option-value-1'    => 'Option Title 1',
    'option-value-2'    => 'Option Title 2',
    'option-value-3'    => 'Option Title 3'
);
```

We can build this type of array like this:

```
//predefine a blank array which we will fill with your options
$choices = array();

//loop through your items and that the values to the $choices array
foreach ($items as $font_value => $item) {
    $choices[$item['slug']] = $item['family']; //I'm assuming your $item array contains some sort of slug to set as the value, otherwise, comment the above out, and uncomment the below:
    // $choices[$item['family']] = $item['family']
}

//set your arguments
$args = array(
    'label'     => 'Fonts Section',
    'section'   => 'ounox-fonts-section',
    'settings'  => 'ounox-fonts-display',
    'type'      => 'select',
    'choices'   => $choices
);

//add the control
$wp_customize->add_control( new WP_Customize_Control( $wp_customize, 'ounox-fonts-display-control', $args));
```

Comment: Thanks a lot man works like a charm sorry I'm really a noob at the backend stuff. I really appreciated man!

Comment: @MarkAnthony anytime :) happy to help :)

Answer (score 2):

A [`foreach`](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php) loop doesn't need a counter so `$i` is redundant.
You're also overriding `$str` with each iteration.

```
$str = '';
foreach ($items as $font_value => $item) {
    $str .= $item['family']; // . '##' in case you need a delimiter
}
```